# How to stop screen from vibrating?

Tags: nvidia, display, flicker, msi

Couldn't find anybody else with the same or similar problem.

After rebooting my computer one time, it just randomly started flickering all over. It's like my LCD screen is a CRT that's not set up right.

Here is what it looks like normally (I can do a screen record and there's no vibration there): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UXITZECXteKVN2J7Chcron-wbkmEQb2u/view?usp=sharing

Here's camera footage of it flickering: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ONTT8hRABrMRg-jqfpUGJLfhyAfrPH-6/view?usp=sharing

I'm running 20.04 with an NVIDIA GTX970M (though the problem persists when switching to Intel graphics) on an MSI GE72 6QF laptop.

I've tried:

- switching to Intel graphic
- rebooting
- updating
- changing refresh rate
- changing resolution

Nothing I do seems to fix it. I don't think the issue is with X since I can record the screen just fine. Any ideas on what could fix it?

I faced this before on Pop_OS! a month ago, and, unable to fix it, I gave up and switched to regular Ubuntu. Despite having this PC running Linux for years, that was the first time I'd run into this issue, and now it's happened again within such a short time!

I really don't want to have to reinstall and set up another OS. Please help!

EDIT:

dmesg shows an error which may be related

```
[  318.746630] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[  318.746640] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  318.746648] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  318.746653] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
```

EDIT 2:

After finding that error and searching, I found a place saying to try testing my memory, so I'm also testing my memory using https://memtest86.com

EDIT 3:

No memory issues were discovered

Comment: i have lenovo-y70-70 nvidia-gtx960m
and i am experience the same problem from yesterday, i didn't find a solution,
it's happen since i update my laptop, so i tried switch to Fedora 34 and it was work for me. after updating fedora the screen start to flickering again so i think something in the upgrade make this happen

Comment: Many similar rendering issues posted today. Try rebooting to previous kernel version. Let us know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm unable to launch into Gnome with 5.4 for whatever reason (though I can open a terminal). However, I still think it fixes the issue. Before, my computer would show a clear splash screen, then go to black, and then the Ubuntu spinning loading boot screen thing would start with my boot splash again, but both would be blurry. This time, they were not blurry. Although I can't get into Gnome yet, I think it might be a kernel issue